# What is the DOCTYPE legacy string for?

Tags: html

In the place of the short DOCTYPE `<!DOCTYPE html>`, according to the [HTML5 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#the-doctype), a DOCTYPE legacy string or an obsolete permitted DOCTYPE string may be used as a DOCTYPE. If an obsolete permitted DOCTYPE string is for backward compatibility then what is a DOCTYPE legacy string for? The standard states that **it is for HTML generators that cannot output HTML markup with the short DOCTYPE**. What in the world are HTML generators? If the HTML generators they are talking about are programs supporting previous versions of HTML5, I think an obsolete permitted DOCTYPE string is a perfect candidate, instead of a DOCTYPE legacy string, because it is the situation that an obsolete permitted DOCTYPE string is looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was primarily for XSLT. XSLT is perfectly capable of producing HTML5, except that in XSLT 1.0 at least, it has no means of describing "output `<!DOCTYPE html>`", so the DOCTYPE legacy string allows XSLT to output valid HTML5.

The phrasing in the spec is just a generified way of permitting that.